# Почему не работают массивы в LINQ to entities

Tags: c#, linq

Есть метод в контроллере, который фильтрует содержимое.

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Search (string[] jsonString)
{
    IQueryable <UploadedFile> res = Context.UploadedFiles;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonString[0]))
    {
        res = res.Where(x => x.FileTitle.Contains(jsonString[0]));
    }

    return View("UploadFilesView", res.ToList());
}
```

В метод прилетает json строка, далее фильтруется и отдается во View.
В коде выше метод возвращается 500 (Internal Server Error).

Если заменить строку

```
res = res.Where(x => x.FileTitle.Contains(jsonString[0]));
```

на

```
var buffer = jsonString[0];

res = res.Where(x => x.FileTitle.Contains(buffer));
```

то все работает. Подскажите, почему так?

Comment: Выяснить, какой `Ехception` приводит к "500 (Internal Server Error)".

Comment: Покажите сообщение об ошибке и StackTrace.

Comment: @SerafimProzorov http://prntscr.com/h0xng9

Почему то в 2017 студии эксепшены не генерируются, через 13 вот такой поолучил

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, еще один момент: что в данном случае Context? Такого свойства ни у ControllerBase, ни у Controller нет. Если это --
 свойство или, Боже упаси, статический класс, реализованные Вами, может быть дело в реализации? И какие версии .NET/библиотек?

Comment: @SerafimProzorov

Это свойство класса BaseController
http://prntscr.com/h0xtci название класса заменил чуть-чуть, а то проект рабочий.

.net 4.7
 Helper.GetContext() возвращает контекст приложения

Comment: @nikola, продолжаем разбор) Уточните, пожалуйста, объект какого типа возвращает Helper.GetContext()? Правильно ли я понял, что наследника DbContext? Просто, если да, то все в общем-то понятно.

Comment: @SerafimProzorov так точно, наследник DbContext.
Нагуглил вот что https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353948/the-linq-expression-node-type-arrayindex-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На приведенном Вами скриншоте есть сообщение об ошибке, гласящее о том, что обращение по индексу не поддерживается в Linq to Entity. Связано это, думаю с тем, что ExpressionBuilder не знает, как перевести его в язык СУБД, которую Вы используете (да, важно не только то, что Вы используете EF, но и то, какой провайдер).

Таким образом, для решения проблемы Вам необходимо поместить нужную Вам строку в локальную переменную.

Comment: Серафим, спасибо большое за помощь, первый раз столкнулся с такой странной ситуацией.